# Variable not being stored for than a second in Javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop

Before I begin, I am aware that there are many other articles in StackOverflow about variables not being stored using the Javascript language. However, the solutions to those were mainly simple, such as declaring the variable outside the loop. Unfortunately, this is not working in my case. Here is the code I have:

```
function authenticationselection() {
  var whichformofauthentication =
    document.getElementsByName("authenticationtypes")
  var len = whichformofauthentication.length
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (whichformofauthentication[i].checked) {
      waytoauthenticate = whichformofauthentication[i].value
      console.log(waytoauthenticate)
      break
    } else {
      continue
    }
  }
}
```

I have declared the variable waytoauthenticate outside of the foor loop, meaning that it is a global variable. When I run this part of the program, the variable waytoauthenticate is set as the value of one fo the radio buttons (which is what this code is for). However, the variable waytoauthenticate is only defined as the value for one second. After a very, very short period of time, the variable becomes it's original value, which is null. Can anyone help me figure out why the variable is only being defined as the value of the radio button for one second. Thanks!

Comment: Show us how the function is being called.

Comment: A better option would be to `return` the value instead of setting a variable in global scope.

Comment: your `waytoauthenticate` is local in scope of `for`

Comment: `var waytoauthenticate`  is declaring a local variable, inside the loop.  Remove `var`

Comment: @csmckelvey there is a button in the HTML code and I added the parameter on click and set it equal to the function. This is the part: onclick=authenticationselection(). Whenever the button is clicked, the function is run. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the variable again in the for loop var waytoauthenticate = whichformofauthentication[i].value . Try removing var as it is already declared outside. hope this helps

Comment: @V.Sambor Hoisting isn't the problem. They're shadowing the variable they have in global scope.

Comment: @4castle  sorry, I don't know why I saw `waytoauthenticate` in top of the function... :-| in this case is clear the variable is masked.

Comment: I removed that and it still didn't work. I had it removed before but for some reason, I added the var in the spot. Sorry about that